# /bin/run.sh: line 4: 18 Segmentation fault (core dumped) ./exe

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int solve(int A, vector<int> &B) {
  vector<int> pre(A);
  vector<int> suff(A);
  vector<int> p;
  vector<int> s;
  int sum = 0;
  int ans = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
    sum = sum + B[i];
  }
  if (sum % 3 != 0)
    return 0;
  sum = sum / 3;

  for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      pre[i] = B[i];
      if (pre[i] == sum) {
        p.push_back(i);
      }
      continue;
    }
    pre[i] = B[i] + pre[i - 1];
    if (pre[i] == sum) {
      p.push_back(i);
    }
  }

  for (int i = A - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i == A - 1) {
      suff[A - 1] = B[A - 1];
      if (suff[i] == sum) {
        s.push_back(i);
      }
      continue;
    }
    suff[i] = B[i] + pre[i + 1];
    if (suff[i] == sum) {
      s.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < p.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = s.size(); j >= 0; j++) {
      if (s[j] > p[i] + 1) {
        ans++;
      }
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

int main() {
  int A = 5;
  vector<int> B = {1, 2, 3, 0, 3};
  cout << solve(5, B);
  return 0;
}
```

The code keeps getting dumped at `pre[i]=B[i]`. The code is very simple for counting the number of ways to split all the elements of the array into 3 contiguous parts so that the sum of elements in each part is the same.

I just made a prefix and suffix sum array.

Comment: ([Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h))

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: _"core dumped"_ means a core file was created. This file contains details about the crash, the call stack, the values of the variables, ... Open it with your debugger and analyze it. It will show you where and why your program crashed.

Comment: Change all `arr[idx]` into `arr.at(idx)` and see where exception pops up. Ex. `int j = s.size(); j >= 0; j++) {
      if (s[j]` is wrong - `s[s.size()]` is  out if bounds

Comment: /bin/run.sh is UNIX/Linux, exe is Windows technology. Are you sure about what you are doing?

Comment: @Dominique Executable files can be called whatever you want, *nix doesn’t care. And I think in this case the file is just `exe`.